# Running 'abc.swf' v/s 'abc.html'

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

(1)When I run the HTTPService code in Flex builder and use Ctrl F11 to run the application then the HttepService runs fine and returns the value. Here, it is run inside an html wrapper 'mypath\Learning\bin-debug\httpServiceissue.html'

(2)The same code when I compile through command-line and then run in Flash PLayer then it won't run. This time its running on its own without html wrapper around.

Also, setting '-use-network = false' in command line (2 approach) allows flash player to load this file. I know that setting flag false will restrict SWF's access  to local machine (no network) and give it access to local resource, but then why it works in Flex builder inside the html wrapper (in 1 case).

Please share you opinion on this.

'mx:HTTPService id="rooms" url="myfile.txt"  fault="httpFaultHandler(event)" resultFormat="e4x" result="httpResultHandler(event)"'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, I've never tried to use the service in that way. It might be a security, or "sandbox" restriction, that unless you've got a "crossdomain.xml" you can't get to any resource that isn't in the same domain. Would the txt file be delivered by some kind of web server when you hit F11?

Good luck, please let us know when you find an answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am working on my local machine. No server environment as such.